# Search API : Elastic Search gives priority to sort instead of title

Tags: 8, search

I am using below modules for Search module:

```
drupal/elasticsearch_connector": "^5.0@alpha"
drupal/search_api: "^1.8"
```

I am using AWS Elastic Search.

What the issue I am facing is, the search result giving priority to sort instead of title.

I am using version 6.3 for elastic search. I cannot upgrade the module or Elastic Search module version due to custom dependency.

Example:

> [https://search-XXXXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch_index_drupal_product_index/_search?source={"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"Test](https://search-XXXXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch_index_drupal_product_index/_search?source=%7B%22query%22:%7B%22bool%22:%7B%22should%22:%5B%7B%22multi_match%22:%7B%22query%22:%22Test)
> item","fields":["title.suggestion"],"fuzziness":1}}]}},"size":12,"sort":[{"field_x":"asc","field_y":"desc"}]}&source_content_type=application/json

If I have above URL then in the result it will give first priority to **field_x** then **field_y** instead of which matches to **Test item**

So if user is going to search with Product title, then he never get the match product at first place.

In search

**admin/config/search/search-api/index/drupal_product_index/processors**

- Ignore case, Stemmer -> I didn't enabled
- Tokenizer -> Enabled with
  default settings for all fields

Am I missing something in configiration?